# passing array values from methods and writing to text output file

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

So i have been slogging threw this project all day and at this point i have no idea where to go.  The project is to create an array of 1000 random integers that are assigned values of 1-10. Next, create an array that stores the frequency of the integers generated. Next, calculate the average of the integers in an array.  And finally, to output all those values to a text file.  I have watched countless videos and am utterly lost at this point.  the examples in the text are for one main method that outputs the text.  I am not sure if i am supposed to put the text file commands into the main method or if i should develop a separate method to handle the text file output.  If so, i am not sure if i pass the arrays from my other methods into a new textFile method or what have you...

Last week was my first time working with multiple methods and this week is my first work with arrays so any guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

This is my code so far.

```
 package randomintegers;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;


 public class RandomIntegers {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int randomNumbers[] = new int [1000];
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<randomNumbers.length;++i){
    randomNumbers[i] = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 10);

    }
    calcFrequency(randomNumbers);
    calcAverage(randomNumbers);
}


public static void calcFrequency(int[] inputArray){
    int[] freq=new int[10];
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<inputArray.length;++i){
        ++freq[inputArray[i]-1];    
    }

    //System.out.println(inputArray);
    //System.out.println( (inputArray[i] + 1) + " occured " + freq[i] + " times" );
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(freq));    }

      public static double calcAverage(int[] randomNumbers)
   {
       int sum = 0;
       for(int i : randomNumbers) sum += i;
        return ((int) sum)/randomNumbers.length;
   }

       public static void textRead(int[] calcAverage int[] calcFrequency)throws FileNotFoundException;{
       Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("randomIntegers.txt"));
       int frequency = input.nextInt();
       int [] outputFreq = new int[10];
   }
```

}

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Writing arrays to file? Or reading them from file?

Comment: writing arrays to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PrintWriter to write to file.

I have commented code, so it will be easy for you to understand.

```
/**
 * Writes array to file.
 * @param array array to write
 * @param fileName name of file in which array will be written
 * @throws FileNotFoundException if creating file fails
 */
public void writeArrayToFile(int [] array, String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
    // create PrintWriter object to write to file
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName);

    // iterate through array, write each element of array to file
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        // write array element to file
        writer.print(array[i]);
        // write separator between array elements to file
        writer.print("\n");
    }

    // done writing, close writer
    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: Does this answers your question?